How to draw a horizontal line from 10:30 to 16:00 for a calculated price?
I am calculating the highest and lowest price from 9:30 AM to 10:30 AM.
After 10:30 AM, I want to 2 plot the horizontal lines for the highest and lowest value from 10:30 AM to 16:00 PM.
The problem is the line are not plotting from 10:30 AM to 16:00 PM.
Below is my code (Bare bones), any help is greatly appreciated.

//@version=5

indicator(title="My Indicator", shorttitle="MI", overlay=true)

// Getting user inputs for Year, Month and Date
int myYear = input.int(title="Year", defval=2024)
int myMonth = input.int(title="Month", defval=5)
int myDate = input.int(title="Date", defval=6)

// Defining Market Start
int myMarketStartHour = 9
int myMarketStartMinute = 30

// Defining First Hour interval
int myFirstEndHour = 10
int myFirstEndMinute = 30

// Defining Market End
int myMarketEndHour = 16
int myMarketEndMinute = 00

// Assigning the start, first hour and end intervals
int myStartTime = timestamp(myYear, myMonth, myDate, myMarketStartHour, myMarketStartMinute)
int myFirstHourEndTime = timestamp(myYear, myMonth, myDate, myFirstEndHour, myFirstEndMinute)
int myMarketEndTime = timestamp(myYear, myMonth, myDate, myMarketEndHour, myMarketEndMinute)

// Initializing highest and lowest prices
var float lowestPrice = na
var float highestPrice = na

// Checking whether the current bar is within the initial first hour
bool isWithinFirstHour = (time >= myStartTime) and (time < myFirstHourEndTime)

if isWithinFirstHour
    lowestPrice := na(lowestPrice) ? low : math.min(lowestPrice, low)
    highestPrice := na(highestPrice) ? high : math.max(highestPrice, high)

// Plotting lines after initial hour
if not na(lowestPrice)
    line.new(x1=bar_index[1], y1=lowestPrice, x2=bar_index, y2=lowestPrice, width=2, color=color.red)
if not na(highestPrice)
line.new(x1=bar_index[1], y1=highestPrice, x2=bar_index, y2=highestPrice, width=2, color=color.green)


I tried counting bars since start of day, turns out it won't work when the change from a 1 minute to 5 minute chart.
I tried using "Hlines" instead but am getting a conversion error.
